# Stop old thread when new thread is created

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, animation, raspberry-pi

I am destroying my head for four hours now without finding a solution ;(.

I am running a python script on my raspberry pi that drives some Neopixels. The Animation is defined by a websocket message.

On every message i call a function to play the animation, after the animation finishes i make a new request to my backend to retrieve a new Message. This works fine.

Now I want to send new animations to the raspi (triggered by a smartphone) already before the animation has finished. The animation blocks the main thread so the websocket message arrives only after the animation has finished.

---> thats why i run the animation function in a new thread. This way the websocket message is received already while the animation function is still running.
The new message creates a new thread.

And here comes the Problem: Lets imagine the first animation takes 10s to finish and after 5s the new message already created the new Thread. This way we have two threads playing an animation on the same Neopixels at the same time. Its like a small fight.

The best solution would be to stop the thread of the first animation. Because there is no function for killing a thread i thougt about checking a variable in the animation function an return because a return statement ends the function and "destroys" the thread.

This is my code:

```
def set_frame(strip, array, brightness, frameCount, delay, firstThread):
    ArrayIndex = 0
    for f in range(frameCount):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, array[ArrayIndex])
            ArrayIndex += 1
        strip.setBrightness(brightness)
        strip.show()

        // thats what i thought
        if thisIsTheOldThread:
            return
        // but how do I know if there is already a new Thread?

        time.sleep(delay)


def on_message(ws, message):
    jsonMessage = json.loads(message)
    setFrameThread = threading.Thread(target=set_frame, args=(strip, jsonMessage["frame"], jsonMessage["brightness"], jsonMessage["frames"], jsonMessage["delay"]))
    setFrameThread.daemon = True
    setFrameThread.start()
```

If you have another idea i would love to hear it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you use a Lock or Event from threading to synchronise which thread can drive the display?

Comment: Make `on_message` independant from `.Thread` using a `Queue`. Run the *animation* thread forever, waiting to `.get()` a new animation from the `Queue`.

Comment: Which of these two options you do depends whether you want the new animation to interupt the old one or not.

Comment: the new animation should interrupt the old one. I will try those two options tomorrow. Thanks ;)